# Free CSS Drop-Down Menu Framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

Quick Question:

Anyone knows this? :

http://lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/

It uses javascript for -IE6 only, but with javascript frameworks.

Is it possible to run this without a framework?

Comment: this dosnt answer your question, but this is a good alternative i have liked this in the past http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_drop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be used without a js library, but not out of the box.  You'd have to write the js yourself.  All you need is basically "on hover, set the style to display the dropdowns", and "on mouseout, set the stlye to hide the dropdowns."  The key for that is the attachEvent function (for IE only, so if you decide you need other browsers, you'll need a modify the code here).  It's better to stick it in a function so it's easier to work with:

```
function observe(target, eventType, func, useCapture) {
    target = (typeof target=="string") ? document.getElementById(target) : target;
    useCapture = useCapture || false;

    target.attachEvent("on"+eventType, function(event) {func(event, target)});
}
```

You could then use that function to wait for page load, then set up the callbacks for the hover and mouseout:

```
observe(window, "load", function() {
    observe("button1", "mouseover", function() {
        document.getElementById("dropdown1").style.display = "block";
    });
    observe("button1", "mouseout", function() {
        document.getElementById("dropdown1").style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

This is of course a very simplistic example, only using id's to grab your menu buttons and dropdowns, but it gives you an idea how to get it started.

Answer (score 1):

It dosn't need a javascript frameworks its css based, it dosnt even need javascript enabled for it to work

n.parentNode.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.nextSibling.style.visibility = "visible"

Comment: Please read the question. On the site itself the following can be read, too:

JavaScript only for IE. Minimal JavaScript code only for IE 6 or earlier. Can be used with popular JavaScript libraries Jquery or Scriptaculous. Everything else is pure CSS.

Comment: i see no you would not need a framework for it, ill post an example how to use a tiny bit of javascript for IE6